# How to get the react redux reducer to handle CREATE actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My reducer is currently loading cats correctly, but not adding a cat correctly. Here is my reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = []

export default function catReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_CATS_SUCCESS:
     return action.cats
    case types.CREATE_CAT_SUCCESS:
      return [
       ...state.filter(cat => cat.id !== action.cat.id),
       Object.assign({}, action.cat)
      ]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Am I adding the cat incorrectly within: `CREATE_CAT_SUCCESS` incorrectly?

The server is responding to the create API post with the following:

```
[{"name":"aXXXXX","id":3123123}]
```

The API func:

```
  static createCat(cat) {
    const request = new Request('http://localhost:4300/api/v1/skills', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify({cat: cat})
    });


    return fetch(request).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Since you are using the spread operator for your array. Do the same for your objects. `return [...state.filter(cat => cat.id !== action.cat.id), {...action.cat}];`.
Also I'd like to suggest you dont use an array for this kind data.
It seems like you have an ID, go with `{1: {id: 1, name: 'nyan'}}`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm using a rails backend for the API so I'm not sure the ID idea would work?

Comment: I tried your idea `return [...state.filter(cat => cat.id !== action.cat.id), {...action.cat}];` that is still resulting in an error... When I look at the chrome redux extension. I see the action data for cat being added incorrectly.... It should be action > cat > (name, id), what's happening is action > cat > 0 > (name, id) ... any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: actually, I got it to work by changing {...action.cat} to ...action.cat -- hopefully that's ok?

Comment: I havent done anything to deserve an accepted answer. I'm happy though, you made it work. ;)

Comment: oh but you actually have my friend!